# Dynamically show/hide columns in DataTables 1.10

Tags: datatables

Im trying to implement dynamically hide/show on a checkbox (onChange event) using code the example section of the DataTables homepage.

```
function(e){
    //e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('datacolumn'));

    // Get the column API object
    var column = table.column($(this).attr('datacolumn'));

    // Toggle the visibility
    column.visible( ! column.visible() );
}
```

However I get an error. It says table.column is "undefined"

Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

I've tried changing the scope of the table-variable in order for me to interact with it in the console of Chrome. And as far as I can see it just points to a htmlcontent.

**UPDATE**

It worked when I specified the complete path to the object.

```
var column = $('#example').dataTable().api().column($(this).attr('datacolumn'))
```

Comment: Thank you for answering this question as it helped me to reach a solution for myself. I wanted to set a column to no be visible depending on the page the user was view and your solution worked wonders with a slight adaptation. `$('#example').dataTable().api().column( 1 ).visible( false );`

Answer (score 4):

in addition, here is a very simple script
to dynamically add toggle buttons based on table thead content
in a div on top of the table
and bind a click to toggle visibility for each

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
 // for each column in header add a togglevis button in the div
 $("#example thead th").each( function ( i ) {
  var name = table.column( i ).header();
  var spanelt = document.createElement( "button" );
  spanelt.innerHTML = name.innerHTML;      
  
  $(spanelt).addClass("colvistoggle");
  $(spanelt).attr("colidx",i);  // store the column idx on the button
  
  $(spanelt).on( 'click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   // Get the column API object
   var column = table.column( $(this).attr('colidx') );
    // Toggle the visibility
   column.visible( ! column.visible() );
  });
  $("#colvis").append($(spanelt));
 });
} );
```

```html
<div id="colvis"></div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <!-- here your col header -->
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  <!-- here your table data -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```