# toggle visibility script for datatables?

Tags: datatables

i found this here is a very simple script to dynamically add toggle buttons based on table thead content in a div on top of the table and bind a click to toggle visibility for each. I want to  add name in it instead of index number can anyone help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

    // for each column in header add a togglevis button in the div
    $("#example thead th").each( function ( i ) {
        var name = table.column( i ).header();
        var spanelt = document.createElement( "button" );
        spanelt.innerHTML = name.innerHTML;                     

        $(spanelt).addClass("colvistoggle");
        $(spanelt).attr("colidx",i);        // store the column idx on the button

        $(spanelt).on( 'click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault(); 
            // Get the column API object
            var column = table.column( $(this).attr('colidx') );
             // Toggle the visibility
            column.visible( ! column.visible() );
        });
        $("#colvis").append($(spanelt));
    });
} );
<div id="colvis"></div>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <thead>
    <!-- here your col header -->
    </thead>
  <tbody>
  <!-- here your table data -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: here is the link from  where I found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23895816/dynamically-show-hide-columns-in-datatables-1-10  I wan trying to do    $(spanelt).attr("colidx", name ,i);    which didn't work

Comment: That works out of the box with Buttons extension without extra code that you've posted, see [Basic column visibility example](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html).

Comment: yes you  are right, but  I am not using that because I want pop-up in centre and also with  3 lists as I have 40 columns in datatable, so that's why I need name attribute for toggle visibility (in case of col-reodering) and to avoid one long list of columns in one side .

Comment: See [Multi-column layout example](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/layout.html) then.